# Create a Dual Boot System with Windows and Linux with an existing Linux on a SSD

Tags: linux, windows, multi-boot, grub

I had to switch my PC which had a dual boot system, on the main nvme ssd was windows 10, on another ssd was Linux. Now I had to switch to another PC where Windows was preinstalled, - to not loose any data I simply put in my old Linux SSD in my new PC.

Of course this won't enable dual boot, but when I boot from a live usb stick I can only use "try ubuntu" or "install ubuntu" is there any way to tell the installation that there is already an ubuntu installed and that it only needs to do the GRUB part for dual boot?

I found some solutions online, but they all seem not very straight forward. I also found the bcdedit command, but I am unsure if this is the right command for doing such operations.

The screenshot from my disk management looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: Are you booting in legacy/BIOS mode or UEFI mode?

Comment: from the system information under msinfo32 it says UEFI

Comment: Please boot into Windows and post a screenshot from _Disk Management_ ([edit] the question)

Comment: included screenshot in post now